# "The only operator that gives back a value is the de-referencing operator"

Tags: c, operators, dereference, unary-operator

So I am a beginner to C.
I was going through text about l-value and r-value when I came across this in one of my study materials:

*"We talk about l-value and r-value with respect to assignment operator =.
The only operator which gives a value back is the dereferencing
operator."*

This confuses me because don't the increment/decrement operators also give a value? Then how is dereferencing the only operator that gives a value back?

Comment: What is the source of that quote? And perhaps more context? Did the author consider `!`, and `~` as well?

Comment: I read that in one of the text compiled by a professor in my college. It didn't say anything about other operators, just that one line.

Comment: You don't need to edit the string "<closed>" into your title when the question is answered.  It will just confuse people.  I reverted it. If you want to know how question closure works, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is a typo and is supposed to say

> The only operator which gives **an l-value** back is the dereferencing operator.

It isn't strictly true.  For example, the `[]`, `.` and `->` operators also give back lvalues (the standard spells it without a hyphen) so that you can write

```
a[5] = 17;
s.x = 42;
p->y = 17;
```

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with this author.

All operator-expressions, whether, unary, binary or ternary, evaluate into a value.

Even restricting ourselves to unary operators, all ***ten*** of these would seem to *"give a value back"* (eg. The expression evaluates to a value):

`&` - AddressOf: returns the memory address of a variable
`*` - Dereference: returns the value stored at a memory address
`!` - Logical Not
`~` - Binary Not
`++x` - Prefix increment
`x++` - Postfix increment
`--x` - Prefix decrement
`x--` - Postfix decrement
`sizeof(x)` - The Size operator *(not a run-time operation, however)*
`(type)(x)` - The Cast Operator converts a value of one type into another type.

If the sentence was meant to be: *"The only operator which gives a **l-value** back is the dereferencing operator."*, then it makes more sense, but is still imperfect and imprecise:

Examples:

```
y = x;    // Simple Assignment
*y = x;   // Assignment with dereference operator
y[5] = x; // Wait?  Is this another operator forming an L-Value?
y.f = x;  // Another one?
y->f = x; // The author was clearly wrong.
```

Comment: I was wondering, maybe they were talking about an l-value or an r-value? Maybe they forgot to type in the 'l' or the 'r'. Does that make sense?